# Pthread condition variable and no deadlock

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

When I was looking the topic, I found the code from [here](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialPosixThreads.html). As you can see, both threads of functions use same `mutex`. So, how can the other thread be signaled or catch the signal and continue its function even if prior thread owns mutex? How/Why isn't there a deadlock? It's a bit confusing.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

pthread_mutex_t count_mutex     = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t  condition_var   = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;

void *functionCount1();
void *functionCount2();
int  count = 0;
#define COUNT_DONE  10
#define COUNT_HALT1  3
#define COUNT_HALT2  6

main()
{
   pthread_t thread1, thread2;

   pthread_create( &thread1, NULL, &functionCount1, NULL);
   pthread_create( &thread2, NULL, &functionCount2, NULL);

   pthread_join( thread1, NULL);
   pthread_join( thread2, NULL);

   printf("Final count: %d\n",count);

   exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

// Write numbers 1-3 and 8-10 as permitted by functionCount2()

void *functionCount1()
{
   for(;;)
   {
      // Lock mutex and then wait for signal to relase mutex
      pthread_mutex_lock( &count_mutex );     //     <---- Same mutex

      // Wait while functionCount2() operates on count
      // mutex unlocked if condition varialbe in functionCount2() signaled.
      pthread_cond_wait( &condition_var, &count_mutex );
      count++;
      printf("Counter value functionCount1: %d\n",count);

      pthread_mutex_unlock( &count_mutex );

      if(count >= COUNT_DONE) return(NULL);
    }
}

// Write numbers 4-7

void *functionCount2()
{
    for(;;)
    {
       pthread_mutex_lock( &count_mutex );    //     <---- Same mutex

       if( count < COUNT_HALT1 || count > COUNT_HALT2 )
       {
          // Condition of if statement has been met. 
          // Signal to free waiting thread by freeing the mutex.
          // Note: functionCount1() is now permitted to modify "count".
          pthread_cond_signal( &condition_var );
       }
       else
       {
          count++;
          printf("Counter value functionCount2: %d\n",count);
       }

       pthread_mutex_unlock( &count_mutex );

       if(count >= COUNT_DONE) return(NULL);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If one thread owns the 
lock, then the other one can't acquire it before the other one releases it. 
Now if thread A acquired the lock first, it will prevent thread B from 
progressing in the critical section until the lock is released.

---

***Why isn't there a deadlock?***

Reading [this](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/pthread_cond_wait.html):

```
int pthread_cond_wait(pthread_cond_t *cond, pthread_mutex_t *mutex);
```

> This function atomically releases the mutex and cause the calling thread to block on the condition variable cond;

Thread A will release the lock when it hits the `cond_wait`and thread B can progress and signal the condition variable.

Comment: You don't understand what I ask. I ask that both use same mutex, if one of them owns authorization, the other must wait to go in its mutex area. If so, in functionCount1, mutex owned by thread1 and pthread_cond_wait is in progress. At this line does it wait for functionCount2(Thread 2)? OR if thread2 owns mutex, how can the thread1 increment the count? Even if the mutex is already owned by thread2?

Comment: @concurrencyboy try now. The thing that confused you I guess was the fact that thread A will release the lock once it runs the `cond_wait`. Otherwise it will deadlock in that scenario where thread A acquires the lock first.